# Crear timer diferente en tiempo de ejecución

Tags: c#, windows-forms, timer

Hola estoy trabajando con una aplicación de windows forms, que crea "n" botones cada vez que alguien presiona un botón llamado "crear". Tengo un panel donde voy acumulando los botones creados, el punto es que necesito que cuando se cree un nuevo grupo de botones estos inicien con un contador diferente, he probado usando una lista de timers pero aun no logro hacer que funcione de manera independiente entre cada grupo de botones, el contador se reinicia en todos los grupos existentes en el panel cada vez que creo un grupo nuevo. Anexo mi código.

```
    private void crearBotones(int no)
    {
        Timer t = new Timer() { Interval = 1000, Enabled = true };
        t.Tag = no;
        t.Tick += iniciaConteo;
        
       
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            Button b = new Button();
            b.Tag = no;
            b.Text = "";
            b.Size = new Size(50, 20);
            b.Location = new Point(0, panel1.Size.Height - y);
            panel1.Controls.Add(b);
            bs.Add(b);
            panel1.Controls.Add(b);
            y = y + 30;
        }

    }

    private void iniciaConteo(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var timerId = (Timer)sender;
        if (Convert.ToInt32(timerId.Tag) == 1)
        {
            int contador = Convert.ToInt32(label1.Text);
            contador = contador + 1;
            label1.Text = contador.ToString();
            foreach (var i in bs)
            {
                if (Convert.ToInt32(i.Tag) == 1)
                    i.Text = contador.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

deberías de crear dos Timer independientes. En el siguiente código que te agrego, he creado dos cronómetros diferentes en dos label

Como ves, cada cronómetro empieza a funcionar en el momento que des a cada botón de forma independiente

Puedes acaptar el código a tu trabajo, si no te haces a él, por la noche te ayudo, ahora tengo que salir, un saludo

te pongo código:

```
//instancias los cronos en la clase, tienes que agregar dos timer diferentes al formulario, los llamamos relojCrono y relojCronoII
//Ahora un obejto de la clase Stopwatch
Stopwatch cronometro = new Stopwatch();
//Segundo obejto diferente de la clase Stopwatch
Stopwatch cronometroII = new Stopwatch();
```

Ahora los botones:

```
private void btnTimer1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Se va autoincrementando el contador del timer
        relojCrono.Tick += new EventHandler(relojCrono_Tick);
        //si está funcionando
        if (cronometro.IsRunning)
        {
            //lo paramos y cambiamos el texto del botón
            cronometro.Stop();
            btnTimer1.Text = "Iniciar";
        }
        else
        { 
            //si está parado, lo iniciamos y cambiamos el texto del botón
            cronometro.Start();
            btnTimer1.Text = "Detener";
        }

    }
    //botón 2, lo mismo que el primero
    private void btnTimer2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        relojCronoII.Tick += new EventHandler(relojCronoII_Tick);
        if (cronometroII.IsRunning)
        {
            cronometroII.Stop();
            btnTimer2.Text = "Iniciar";
        }
        else
        {
            cronometroII.Start();
            btnTimer2.Text = "Detener";
        }
    }
```

Y ahora los eventos de cada Timer

```
private void relojCrono_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //si está funcionando el objeto
        if (cronometro.IsRunning)
        {
            //en el label timer 1 formateamos la salida
            this.lblTimer1.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}:{3:00}", cronometro.Elapsed.Hours, cronometro.Elapsed.Minutes, cronometro.Elapsed.Seconds, cronometro.Elapsed.Milliseconds / 10);
        }

    }
    //el segundo objeto hace lo mismo en el label Timer 2
    private void relojCronoII_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (cronometroII.IsRunning)
        {

            this.lblTimer2.Text = String.Format("{0:00}:{1:00}:{2:00}:{3:00}", cronometroII.Elapsed.Hours, cronometroII.Elapsed.Minutes, cronometroII.Elapsed.Seconds, cronometroII.Elapsed.Milliseconds / 10);
        }
    }
```

Espero te sirva para hacerte una idea, ya me cuentas

Comment: Mas o menos capto la idea, pero me funcionaria para "n" cantidad de botones?

Comment: La creación de los botones sería totalmente independiente de los Timer. A ver si me explico. Imagina que en lugar de "btnTimer1_Click", fuese "metodoIniciarCronometro1". En tu código, justo a la hora de crear cada grupo de botones, vas llamando a cada método anterior, que puedes tener todos cuántos quieras. O sea, creas los botones y llamas al iniciaConteo, lo sustituyes por el metodoIniciarCronometro1. Con un if y un contador vas validando que esté el primer cronómetro.IsRunning y si lo está, saltas al segundo y así sucesivamente

Comment: Genial!!, muchas gracias por la ayuda, intentaré implementarlo , ya te digo como me va.

Comment: Intentare estar atengo a ver si lo consigues o si puedo seguir ayudando, un saludo

Comment: Si el código de los timer era lo que buscabas, cierra la pregunta dándole al Check aceptando la respuesta, porfa. Así se quitan preguntas sin respuesta. Un saludo